# I need to implement a java based client-server protocol on rest protocol, that too the commands are fired thorugh wsdl file

Tags: java, wsdl

I need to write a java client-server program on rest protocol that too the commands on client side are given through wsdl file. How would it work for wsdl on rest, as i know for wsdl on SOAP. Please suggest.